# Line 57:7: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, syntax-error

Getting this error, i don't know why, use this same method in many files in same project.
Using this function to create an array of Options for `React-Select` (Multi select) Library.

```
import { Button, Grid, IconButton, MenuItem, Modal, Select, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
// import { GridCloseIcon } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import MultiSelect from '../../../components/MultiSelect'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { AddModule, fetchModulesCategories } from '../../../redux/Modules/ModuleActions';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cancel';
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
```

```
  Line 57:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw
  an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Comment: post complete code as a lot of times the error message line number is not exactly where the error is. You can share a sandbox link as well if you have one

Comment: Which line is 57?

Comment: I have added full source code

Comment: Remove the `console.log statement`, and also don't post question. Edit your question with existed question. @mohit agarwal